# How to get ifr_hwaddr.sa_data to char

Tags: c

How to get this:

```
printf(" %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
(unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0],
(unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1],
(unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2],
(unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3],
(unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4],
(unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]);
```

into this(store in variable, not print it):

```
char mac[18];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char mac[19]; /* one extra for terminating '\0'; 
                     You may want to make it a little larger
                     still, just to be sure. */

    sprintf(mac, " %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", 
        (unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0],
        (unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1],
        (unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2],
        (unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3],
        (unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4],
        (unsigned char)item->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]);

    printf("%s\n", mac); // string was "printed" to mac array!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to save it into a variable, not print it

Comment: Sprintf (starts with s) writes the formatted output to the char array instead of to stdout. Take a look at stdio.h. You'll find printf, fprintf (writes formatted string to file) and sprintf (writes formatted string to string). Just try the code I posted.